# Parse.com notifications from Web Console

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform

Im using parse.com to push ios notifications through the web interface. I'd like to be able to retrieve sent pushes and display them. Is there a way to retrieve previous pushes or do I have to create a PFObject when a notification is received and fetch it with a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically retrieve them from Parse, however your idea of saving them as a PFObject is probably a good one.

If you use CloudCode you can send a push after a save of that object.

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Look for afterSave functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your own logic by cloud code.

Once you send push notification, save it into a separate table. If you want to retrieve, you could just make a query to your separate table.